# How to show session messages at front end in magento 2 beta

Tags: magento2, session, magento2-dev-beta, global-messages

I want to show an error or success message in my magento 2 module. I have extended my front-end controller with the class name `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action`. Then I redirect client to home page using following code

```
$this->messageManager->addError($SomeMessage);
$resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
$resultRedirect->setPath($base_path);
```

Everything works fine but this line never prints the error

```
$this->messageManager->addError($SomeMessage);
```

Comment: Are you have to show messages on storefront or in admin panel?

Comment: I want to show messages on storefront

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have faced issue related to display message in Magento2 Beta source. In some source by default display error and success message but in some case it do not display then follow below steps.

Step 1: I have created Message.php file in my custom module in Darsh\Crud\Block\Message.php

```
namespace Darsh\Crud\Block;

class Message extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Messages {

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\Factory $messageFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,       
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $messageFactory,
            $collectionFactory,
            $messageManager,
            $data
        );       
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $this->addMessages($this->messageManager->getMessages(true));       
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

}
```

Step 2: Added message block in to handeler in Darsh\Crud\view\frontend\layout\crud_index_form.xml

```
   <referenceContainer name="page.messages">
        <block class="Darsh\Crud\Block\Message" name="darsh.crud.message" />
    </referenceContainer>
```

Please add opening and closing Tag <> for layout handle.

Now you can see your custom message added in Darsh\Crud\Controller\Index\Form.

If you face any issue please see Example module on https://github.com/Darshanmodi1427/Magento2_Crud_Operation.git

Comment: After some modifications i got the results :)

Answer (score 7):

In layout file i have used the below code. now i got the message in frontend.

```
<referenceContainer name="page.messages">            
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="ajax.message.placeholder" template="Magento_Theme::html/messages.phtml"/>
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Messages" name="messages" as="messages" template="Magento_Theme::messages.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: Thankyou Marius

Comment: Thanks @Naveen. Works fine in Magento 2 in my custom module

Answer (score 6):

I have faced the same issue and I was able to fix it by adding the following in my layout file:

```
<body>
    <!-- your layout content -->
    <referenceContainer name="page.messages">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Messages" name="messages" as="messages"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

This should fix it ;)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried returning your last line of the code?

```
return $resultRedirect->setPath($base_path);
```

The actual `addError` function looks fine unless the `$SomeMessage` variable is empty, have you checked that as well?

If that fails maybe you can try redirecting using the `_redirect` function instead like:

```
$this->_redirect('*/*/');
```

Maybe the `resultRedirect` function clears the message session so your message never gets displayed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I have added message using $resultRedirect object with

```
$resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect('crud/index/form'));
```

Please see below controller code

```
namespace Darsh\Crud\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class Post extends \Magento\Contact\Controller\Index {
//class Post extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {


    public function execute() {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

        if (!$data) {
            $this->_redirect('crud/index/form');
            return;
        }

        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        try {
            $model = $this->_objectManager->create('Darsh\Crud\Model\Crud');
            if (isset($_FILES['image']['name']) && $_FILES['image']['name'] != '') {
                try {
                    $uploader = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader', array('fileId' => 'image'));
                    $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png'));
                    $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                    $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);
                    $mediaDirectory = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Filesystem')
                            ->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
                    $config = $this->_objectManager->get('Darsh\Crud\Model\Crud');
                    $result = $uploader->save($mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('bannerslider/images'));
                    unset($result['tmp_name']);
                    unset($result['path']);
                    $data['image'] = $result['file'];
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    $data['image'] = $_FILES['image']['name'];
                }
            } else if (isset($data['image']['delete'])) {
                $data['image'] = '';
            } else if (isset($data['image']['value'])) {
                $data['image'] = $data['image']['value'];
            }

            $model->setData($data);
            $model->setStoreId($this->storeManager->getStore()->getId())
                        ->setStores([$this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()])
                        ->save();
            try {
                $model->save();
                $this->messageManager->addSuccess(
                        __('Thanks for contacting us with your comments and questions. We\'ll respond to you very soon.')
                );
                //$this->_redirect('crud/index/form');
                //return;
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError(
                        __('We can\'t process your request right now. Sorry, that\'s all we know.'));
                //$this->_redirect('crud/index/form');
                //return;
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError(
                    __('We can\'t process your request right now. Sorry, that\'s all we know.')
            );
            //$this->_redirect('crud/index/form');
            //return;
        }

        $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect('crud/index/form'));

        return $resultRedirect;
    }

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try using XDEBUG, set break point at your controller action. Maybe it was duplicated redirect and making lost messages in manager.