# How to use messageManager to show an error after redirect

Tags: magento2, messages

I have a Module which processes a Post action, and then redirects.

Now there are error cases, and I would like to show messages for them to the users.

I already know, that this code adds the message to the session.

```
$this->messageManager->addError(
   $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Escaper')->escapeHtml($message)
);
```

But I dont see how to trigger the rendering.

Currently it is only shown when i execute another action, which already uses this in a working way.

Like for example the login with wrong password.

Comment: you find any solution to this problem?

Comment: there is a built-in checking function already. See my answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/219143/33057

Comment: this code where is added?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but I'm giving it a shot.
You can retrieve the messages like this:

```
$messages = $this->messageManager->getMessages(true);
```

where `messageManager` is an instance of `\Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface`.

In the core, this is used for ajax calls in order to return the error messages in the json response like this (`\Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Move`):

```
$block = $this->layoutFactory->create()->getMessagesBlock();
...
$block->setMessages($this->messageManager->getMessages(true));
$resultJson = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();

return $resultJson->setData([
    'messages' => $block->getGroupedHtml(),
    'error' => $error
]);
```

For actions with output you shouldn't do anything (I think). The `default.xml` layout file from the `Magento_Theme` module already contains this block `<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Messages" name="messages" as="messages" template="Magento_Theme::messages.phtml"/>` that should handle the messages.

[Side note]:
Don't use `$this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Escaper')->escapeHtml($message)`. Inject in your constructor an instance of `Magento\Framework\Escaper` and use that.

Comment: The loginPost action is also able to trigger this, and it does a redirect to the login page after this and shows it then. Thats the case I have, too. No ajax, no same page.

Comment: That's what I said...this should be handled by default. You should not need to make any changes. The session message should be displayed on the next page.

Comment: And thats why I do this question. Because its not. I even redirect to the same page(login) so obviously there is an additional step needed. As I said, even on the login page my message is only shown after i tried the login which posts its own message

Comment: OK. I'll dig deeper. This looks strange to me.

Comment: i have the same issue check my question http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/76515/how-to-show-session-messages-at-front-end-in-magento-2-beta?noredirect=1#comment108739_76515. i tried all possible solutions but no luck

Comment: @Flyingmana. I found something. The session messages are retrieved after a call is made to `/customer/section/load/`. Maybe that helps.

Comment: i also made call to /customer/section/load/ in my custom module and the response have the error or success message but does not show any message at page

Comment: @Marius you found any solution?

Comment: Sorry. Nothing worth mentioning so far

Comment: I was also trying to find solution for this but with no luck yet. However, for now you can go to the cart and find your messages there ;)

Comment: Be careful suggesting this, the true flag will clear messages so future calls won't be able to get them

Comment: @Marius I need your help brother..

Answer (score 26):

You need to use object injection method on ur module action class to inject the message manager object into it, i provided an example of what u can do. Hope it helps

```
class Example
{
    protected $_messageManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager
    ) {
        $this->_messageManager = $messageManager;
    }

    public function method( ) {
        ..
        $message = '...';
        $this->_messageManager->addError($message);
        ..
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any getError function? i want to fetch the message

Comment: [the `addError` method is deprecated](https://github.com/pepe1518/magento2/blob/master/vendor/magento/framework/Message/ManagerInterface.php) should be addErrorMessage now

Comment: @jafarpinjar , nope. I would change it in translation , but if you cant change it in translation, you can get the error message by event observer and manipulate it there.

Comment: @jamil , yes agreed. addError is depreciated but still supported on ver 2.3.1 :)

Comment: use addErrorMessage instead.

Answer (score 5):

you can also find the message manager accessible through `$context` that is injected into actions constructors:

```
class yourAction extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /** var ... */
    protected $_messageManager;

    public function __construct(Context $context)
    {
        $this->_messageManager = $context->getMessageManager();
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
```

Next just use as mentioned in answers above

> $this->_messageManager->addError($message);

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

For me it looks like you need to add special block for your messages if you want to show them in non-JS way.

For example in Magento\Checkout\view\frontend\layout\checkout_cart_index.xml there is:

```
<referenceContainer name="page.messages">
    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\ValidationMessages" name="checkout.cart.validationmessages"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

`Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\ValidationMessages` block extends core `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Messages` block which is responsible for rendering messages.

Blocks defined in `default.xml` are for JS messages only I believe.

Comment: How do you add it to `checkout_index_index.xml`?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at

**vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/web/js/customer-data.js**

```
/**
 * Events listener
 */
$(document).on('ajaxComplete', function (event, xhr, settings) {
    var sections,
        redirects;

    if (settings.type.match(/post|put/i)) {
        sections = sectionConfig.getAffectedSections(settings.url);

        if (sections) {
            customerData.invalidate(sections);
            redirects = ['redirect', 'backUrl'];

            if (_.isObject(xhr.responseJSON) && !_.isEmpty(_.pick(xhr.responseJSON, redirects))) {
                return;
            }
            customerData.reload(sections, true);
        }
    }
});
```

As we can see, there is a **built-in checking function already**. If our response contains keywords: `'redirect', 'backUrl'`, the message will load after redirecting.

- After ajax complete, the customer will be invalidated. This will be "trigger" reloading message session.
- Checking keywords: `'redirect', 'backUrl'`.