# How to display Notification Message in a page

Tags: messages, notification, magento-2.2.1, success-message

I use magento 2.2.1 version. I just tried to show notification messages and I use [this code](https://github.com/ajzele/B05032-Foggyline_Office).

You can go to Controller/Test/Crud.php. I also injected \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager. But I couldn't see messages.

What is wrong in this code or what I need to show the messages ?

```
class Crud extends \Foggyline\Office\Controller\Test
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $_messageManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager
    )
    {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->_messageManager = $messageManager;


        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Url like http://magento2.ce/index.php/foggyline_office/test/crud/
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $this->_messageManager->addSuccess('Success-1');
        $this->_messageManager->addSuccess('Success-2');
        $this->_messageManager->addNotice('Notice-1');
        $this->_messageManager->addNotice('Notice-2');
        $this->_messageManager->addWarning('Warning-1');
        $this->_messageManager->addWarning('Warning-2');
        $this->_messageManager->addError('Error-1');
        $this->_messageManager->addError('Error-2');

        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check by extending `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action` in your controller instead of `\Foggyline\Office\Controller\Test` ?

Comment: ok I will try now

Comment: it doesn't run. Can anyone clone that git and try in local enviroment?

Comment: I have just installed the module on Magento 2.2.0 and I am able to see the messages after an alert box on the page. So your code is correct there is something else in your setup which is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need inject the message manager object into the constructor.

class Example
{

```
protected $_messageManager;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager
) {
    $this->_messageManager = $messageManager;
}

public function method( ) {
    ..
    $message = '...';
    $this->_messageManager->addError($message);
    ..
}
```

}

Check this link below

[How to use messageManager to show an error after redirect](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/83138/how-to-use-messagemanager-to-show-an-error-after-redirect)

Comment: I tried this already. Still not working.

Comment: Did you inject message manager interface into your constructor!. Paste your new codes. It should work. You can not directly use messageManager. Your codes are wrong. You must write $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage('Success-1'); into execute() method of your controller class. Check properly please

Comment: yes of course I have injected. not working. I referenced this code  https://github.com/ajzele/B05032-Foggyline_Office and injected  message manager interface.

Comment: could you clone the module to test it ?

Comment: I checked your Crud.php and did not find anything that you learned from the answer. Create a protected $_messageManager; Pass \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager into your constructor. Initialize $this->_messageManager = $messageManager; into public function __construct and then use $this->_messageManager->addError($message); into your execute method

Comment: I have already did it. Check the updated question.

Comment: It should be $this->_messageManager->addSuccess('Success-1'); Underscore is missing _messageManager. After this, compile and run. It will work

Comment: oh god. yes. :) I updated. Now I try again. hope it works.

Comment: sorry but it is really not working. And there is no error.

Comment: It must be some other error in your page. Check log files. Clear generated/ folder at root and refresh the page if you are in developer mode.I hope you are using Magento 2.2 ! Try with a new test page to test messageManager.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `addError` try `addErrorMessage`,

So instead of

```
$this->_messageManager->addError($message);
```

do

```
$this->_messageManager->addErrorMessage($message);
```

or

```
$this->_messageManager->addSuccessMessage($message);
```