# Exception in controller

Tags: magento2, controllers, exception

in my controller, I have this code (I'm getting last order through a form):

```
...
    foreach($array as $item){
                        try {
                            $product = $this->_productRepository->getById($item['product_id']);
                            $product_id = $product->getId();
                        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
                            echo $e;
                        }

                        if(isset($product_id)){
                            $param = array(
                                    'product' => $item['product_id'],
                                    'qty' => $item['qty']
                                );


                 }
                }
```

I want to display a simple message on my view. The exception is way to big, I want only to show 'product doesn't exist'. How can I do that ? I saw that I can achieve this with "message manager", but how can I get the exception from the controller to my view ?

Comment: $e->getMessage()tried this?

Comment: $this->messageManager->addError('product doesn't exist');

Comment: Where do I add this ? On frontend ?

Comment: No in place of echo $e;

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/83138/how-to-use-messagemanager-to-show-an-error-after-redirect

Comment: Yes that's it, I've understood a few minutes ago, thanks !