# How to show success message in session Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, magento-2.1, magento-2.0.2

In magento 1 i can do it like this

```
$session            = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');
$session->addSuccess($this->__('Your Request has been received. One of our sales representatives will contact you shortly.'));
```

Same thing how can i do it in Magento2? Tried [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/76515/how-to-show-session-messages-at-front-end-in-magento-2-beta) but not working .

Comment: You can set and get the values by session, do you want use only session ? have you tried Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager

Comment: i have tried this but no luck.

Comment: do you want use only session ?

Comment: I am trying to show a success message after submit the form successfully.

Comment: @ Naveen Check my answer added

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In Magento 2, we can do achieve this in two steps:

First, we need to assign the message to 'messageManager' from your module as below:

```
$this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('This is a success message.'));
```

Secondly, we need to assign a placeholder for the message through frontend layout xml used in the module as given below inside the `<body>` tag:

```
<referenceContainer name="page.messages">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="ajax.message.placeholder" template="Magento_Theme::html/messages.phtml"/>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Messages" name="messages" as="messages" template="Magento_Theme::messages.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

The above layout update will make use of the magento's message template to display the messages.

Comment: ,How to I add this reference container in backend

Comment: Is the XML really needed here?

Answer (score 15):

Magento2 is using MessageInterface to add all message, please use below code to show Messages

Magento Message Framework class

```
use \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;
```

use below code in your file to add messages,

```
protected _messageManager;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context, 
    \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->_messageManager = $messageManager;
}
```

and then add below functions in your methods to show messages:

```
$this->_messageManager->addError(__("Error Message"));
$this->_messageManager->addWarning(__("Warning"));
$this->_messageManager->addNotice(__("Notice"));
$this->_messageManager->addSuccess(__("Success Message"));
```

I hope this will help you fixing your issue.

Comment: which file i want to add this code

Answer (score 3):

You can try below code to add success or error Messages.

`$this->messageManager` was in parent class calling from

**\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action**

> $this->messageManager = $context->getMessageManager();

```
class Post extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function execute()
    {

        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();       
        $question = $objectManager->create('Myvendor\Mymodule\Model\Feedback');

        /****** set your data *********/
        $question->setData($data);
        $question->save();

        $this->messageManager->addSuccess( __('Thanks for your valuable feedback.') );

        /* ***** OR
        $this->messageManager->addError('There is something went wrong');
        $this->_redirect('*/');
        return;
    }
}
```

You can assign messages to `messageManager`

```
$this->messageManager->addError(__("Error"));
$this->messageManager->addWarning(__("Warning"));
$this->messageManager->addNotice(__("Notice"));
$this->messageManager->addSuccess(__("Success"));
```

You can find some more information on how to [Display notification messages](https://www.extensionsmall.com/blog/display-notification-messages-in-magento-2/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do not use the Object Manager directly.

Answer (score 2):

Custom layout file

```
<referenceContainer name="page.messages">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Messages" name="messages" as="messages"/>
 </referenceContainer>
```

Use this in your custom layout file to show the Error message and Success message for your custom template file.

Custom Controller file

```
 try{
        $school_model->save();
        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(
                    __('Thanks for Submission'));
    }catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->messageManager->addError(
                    __('We can\'t process your request right now. Sorry, that\'s all we know.'));   
    }
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    return;
```

Comment: If you post code as an answer, please at least explain
briefly what this code is doing and where it belongs. Answers with code but no
explanation are rarely useful.

Comment: @Jeeva Chezhiyan, I nees to add this in backend , where i need to add the above reference container

Comment: i am calling tge controller using ajax, but i don't want to send response success status to js,i just need to show my message using messagemanager, is this possible