# Magento notifications are not showing in the frontend

Tags: magento2, messages, global-messages, notification

I am using Magento 2. I am trying to display magento notifications on the page of custom module. I have followed these posts:
[How to show session messages at front end in magento 2 beta](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/76515/how-to-show-session-messages-at-front-end-in-magento-2-beta/127684#127684)
[How to use messageManager to show an error after redirect](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/83138/how-to-use-messagemanager-to-show-an-error-after-redirect)
[How to show success message in session Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/127476/how-to-show-success-message-in-session-magento2)

I am using **messageManager** and message block is being rendered in the page, but messages are still not displayed. While these messages (that I add) are displayed in regular magento page.

I notice that scripts **messages.js** and **messageList.js** are not present in the page. Does it have anything to do with that? If yes how to add them?

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="page.messages">            
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Messages" name="messages" as="messages" template="Magento_Theme::messages.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>`

Comment: this is my layout file `<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="page.messages">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="ajax.message.placeholder" template="Magento_Theme::html/messages.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Messages" name="messages" as="messages" template="Magento_Theme::messages.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>`

Comment: as you can see the block is there and it is also present in the web page