# Review tab is not showing in magento2 product page

Tags: magento2, product-page

I have created a custom theme but the review tab is not showing on product page. If I change my custom theme for default luma theme than the review tab starts displaying on product page.

Is there someone who can guide me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7):

Add review tab in custom theme's **`catalog_product_view.xml`** in **`product.info.details`** block

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<block class="Magento\Review\Block\Product\Review" name="reviews.tab" as="reviews" template="Magento_Review::review.phtml" group="detailed_info">
    <block class="Magento\Review\Block\Form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form">
        <container name="product.review.form.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" label="Review Form Fields Before"/>
    </block>
</block>
```

**Final catalog_product_view look like this:**

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.details" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/details.phtml" after="product.info.media">
...
...

<block class="Magento\Review\Block\Product\Review" name="reviews.tab" as="reviews" template="Magento_Review::review.phtml" group="detailed_info">
    <block class="Magento\Review\Block\Form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form">
        <container name="product.review.form.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" label="Review Form Fields Before"/>
    </block>
</block>

...
</block>
```

Comment: Hi Prince, thanks a lot it works but after submitting review it store and not display success message on product page and when I click on other page or link  it display success message on that page.

Comment: Plz check this queue: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/76515/how-to-show-session-messages-at-front-end-in-magento-2-beta OR ask a new question about success message because it is not related to review tab.

Comment: @PrincePatel, yes same issue message not displayed after form submit,

Answer (score 4):

Review block will not work in custom Magento 2 theme.

To show Review tab on the product page you should have to add JsLayout at the following location.

app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Review/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

Add the following code in above located file.

```
<referenceBlock name="product.review.form">
 <arguments>
    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="review-form" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Review/js/view/review</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: Working fine for me !!

Answer (score 0):

Follow this guide to show the review tab on PDP.
https://mage2.pro/t/topic/383

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/194548)